# display back button when user is not on homepage

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

When a user moves from the homepage to the login back, the user can't find a back button at the top of the header

```
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$ionicConfigProvider){
    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position("standard");
    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.style("standard");
        $stateProvider
        .state('tabs',{
            url: '/tab',
            abstract:true,
            templateUrl:'templates/index_tabs.html',

        })



         .state('tabs.index',{
            url:'/index',
            views:{
            'list-index':{
            templateUrl:  'templates/index_files/index.html',
            }
            }
        })

        .state('tabs.login',{
            url:'/login',
            views:{
            'list-login':{
            templateUrl:  'templates/index_files/login.html',
            }
            }
        })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/index')
     })
```

login.html

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive" align-title="center">
      <h1 class="title">Sign In</h1>
          </ion-header-bar>

          <ion-view>
          <ion-content>
          <div ng-app="starter" ng-controller="userlogin_controller">
            <form id="login_form" name="login_form" method="post" action="">
              <div class="list list-inset">
                <div class="list modal">
                  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                  <span class="input-label">Email</span>

                  <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="someone@example.com" ng-model="userlogin.email" required="required" autocomplete="off"/>

                  <div class="error" ng-show="login_form.email.$error.email">Email is not valid</div>


                  </label>
                  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label"> <span class="input-label">Password</span>
                    <input name="password" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password here" ng-model="userlogin.password" />
                  </label>
                  </br>
                  <p align="center">
                    <button ng-disabled="login_form.$invalid" class="button button-positive" ng-click="userlogin()"> Go viva</button>
                  </p>
                  </br>
                  <p align="center"><a href="#/tab/forgotpassword">Forgot your password?</a></p>

                  <p align="center"><button class="icon icon-left ion-social-facebook button button-positive button-small" ng-click="facebookSignIn()">Sign Up with Facebook</button></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </form>

          </ion-content>

          </ion-view>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <!-- <script src="cordova.js"></script>-->

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">

      <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
     Back
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>

      <ion-nav-view>

      </ion-nav-view>

  </body>
</html>
```

Any help with this on how to make the back button appear when users navigates away from the homepage?

Comment: Try with this code after `ion-view` in login.html page `<ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
        <button class="button button-icon  icon ion-chevron-left">
        </button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>`

Comment: @Anilkumar, can you put your code into my script for me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your login.html page with these code

`<ion-view>
   <ion-nav-bar> <ion-nav-buttons side="primary"> <button class="button button-icon icon ion-chevron-left"> </button> </ion-nav-buttons> </ion-nav-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <div ng-app="starter" ng-controller="userlogin_controller">
          <form id="login_form" name="login_form" method="post" action="">
            <div class="list list-inset">
              <div class="list modal">
                <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                   <span class="input-label">Email</span>
                   <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="someone@example.com" ng-model="userlogin.email" required="required" autocomplete="off"/>
                    <div class="error" ng-show="login_form.email.$error.email">Email is not valid</div>
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label"> <span class="input-label">Password</span>
                  <input name="password" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password here" ng-model="userlogin.password" />
                </label>
              </br>
              <p align="center">
                <button ng-disabled="login_form.$invalid" class="button button-positive" ng-click="userlogin()"> Go viva</button>
              </p>
              </br>
                <p align="center"><a href="#/tab/forgotpassword">Forgot your password?</a></p>
                <p align="center"><button class="icon icon-left ion-social-facebook button button-positive button-small" ng-click="facebookSignIn()">Sign Up with Facebook</button></p>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
      </ion-content>
</ion-view>`